# why does this bash script fail to modify a file?

Tags: bash, shell

this 3.sh reads the contents of the file specified in the first argument and replaces ALL occurrences of the words specified in the **second** argument to **second last** argument by the word specified in the **last** argument.

```
    $cat file.txt 
    Hello NZ! How r u? Hey NZ! How r u?
    $./3.sh file.txt NZ Hey Baby
    Hello Baby! How r u? Baby Baby! How r u?
```

the following is my code:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    list=($1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9)
    str="`cat ${list[0]}`"
    for ((i=1; i<$#-1; i++))
      do
      str="${str//${list[i]}/${list[i+1]}"
    done
    echo $str > $1
```

Comment: One problem is that you have one too few `}` in the `str="${str..."` line. You should probably use `file="${1:?}"; shift` to capture the file name separately. As long as the files are small, this should work, but it is tempting to use `sed` rather than raw `bash`.

Comment: The error message `unexpected EOF while looking for matching '"'` tells you that one of your closing `"` is not recognized. You can then  focus on the two closing `"` as potential problem spots, and that quickly leads to the missing closing `}`, as pointed out by @JonathanLeffler. Try to post the error message, too, if you can.

Answer (score 1):

As commenters pointed out, you were simply missing a closing `}` there, so the quick fix is:

```
str="${str//${list[i]}/${list[i+1]}}"
```

But you could rewrite this much nicer, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$1; shift
replacement=$1; shift
str=$(cat "$file")
for pattern; do
    str=${str//$pattern/$replacement}
done
echo "$str" > "$file"
```

This changes the usage though, to this new pattern:

```
./script.sh FILE REPLACEMENT PATTERN1 PATTERN2 PATTERN3 ...
```

But I think it's worth it, because the logic is cleaner, simpler.

Btw this version also fixes other potential problems you might have, for example with spaces in the filename, or sequences of spaces in the text file you're rewriting.